# Constraint on a group of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, postgresql-9.6, exclusion-constraint

For a simple example, let's say I have a `list` table and a `list_entry` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE list 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
);

CREATE TABLE list_entry 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    list_id INTEGER NOT NULL
        REFERENCES list(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    position INTEGER NOT NULL,
    value TEXT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT list_entry__position_in_list_unique
        UNIQUE(list_id, position)
);
```

I now want to add the following constraint: all list entries with the same `list_id` have `position` entries that form a contiguous sequence starting at `1`.

And I have no idea how.

I first thought about `EXCLUDE` constraints, but that seems to lead nowhere.

Could of course create a trigger, but I'd prefer not to, if at all possible.

Comment: If you enforced this as a constraint, then removing an entry would be quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with a constraint - you would need to implement the logic in code (e.g. using triggers, stored procedures, application code, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of such way to use constraints. Normally a `trigger` would be the most straightforward choice, but in case you want to avoid using them, try to get the current `position` number for the `list_entry` with the `list_id` you're about to insert, e.g. inserting a `list_entry` with `list_id` =  1:

```
INSERT INTO list_entry (list_id,position,value) VALUES 
(1,(SELECT coalesce(max(position),0)+1 FROM list_entry WHERE list_id = 1),42);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b1d30e20309f9841b18ffcb1dc992016)

Comment: Updating the list like this does of course not account for entry position swapping and such.

Comment: @User1291, no it does not.. and it was also not stated in your question :-D how are the list items going to be maintained? can items be deleted or positions be updated? have you considered using a timestamp instead of an integer to maintain the order?

Comment: Well, the user will be able to delete arbitrary items and add new ones at arbitrary positions... it just occured to me I could probably build something like a doubly-linked list with the entries. Though mapping that to in-app entities would be a pain. XD

Comment: @User1291 I see.. in that case I really think a `trigger` might be the best option. You can easily control what's being inserted or updated from there.. and it's imho easier to maintain ;) cheers and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generated column to reference the previous number in the list, essentially building a linked list. This works in Postgres:

```sql
create table list_entry 
(
  pos integer not null primary key,
  val text not null,
  
  prev_pos integer not null
    references list_entry (pos)
    generated always as (greatest(0, pos-1)) stored
);
```

In this implementation, the first item (`pos=0`) points to itself.